Using Convexity to Compare Functions
I've been given the question:
Show $\frac{e^a + e^b}{2}$ > $e^\frac{a+b}{2}$.
The solution involves checking the convexity of both sides of this inequality, but I don't understand the intuition behind this approach or how to execute it. Appreciate any help!

The RHS can be written as $\sqrt{ e^a e^b },$ so the weak version of the inequality is true by AM-GM.

The weak version of this inequality can be obtained by Jensen's inequality for $f(x)=e^x$. Since $f$ is a convex function, by Jensen's inequality we obtain $$\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2} \ge f \left( \frac{a+b}{2} \right)$$ which is nothing but $$\frac{e^a + e^b}{2} \ge e^{ \frac{a+b}{2} }.$$

The inequality you have doesn't need convexity to prove. By AM-GM, $\frac{e^a+e^b}{2} \geq \sqrt{e^ae^b} = e^{\frac{a+b}{2}}$. Eqaulity when $a=b$. I'm going to assume the question says $a$ does not equal $b$.
Using convexity is easy as well. We have that $e^x$ is convex, so by definition of convexity you can solve the problem.

There is a typo in your answer.
